# IP PROTECTION NOT ENABLED. Unexpected mysql error 1064 accessing iptable

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I have successfully restored a Joomla backup website on localhost but there seems to be a 1064 error. Have anyone encountered this error before? We only have this error when we install the Joomla Backup on the mac. We don't have the error on server though. Would appreciate your help. Thanks. Other details:
XAMPP OS X 5.5.30, PHP 5.5.30.

IP PROTECTION NOT ENABLED! Unexpected mysql error 1064 accessing iptable: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `hackcount` >= 3' at line 1 SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) from `#__mi_iptable` WHERE ip = AND `hackcount` >= 3

Answer (score 0):

This is from http://www.mmleoni.net/sql-iniection-lfi-protection-plugin-for-joomla Go into your database and access the #__extensions table. Search for plugin name 'System - Marco's SQL Injection - LFI Interceptor'. Set enabled to 0.

You can re-enable the plugin after you update it or fix the error etc.